# Starting to ending number

Tags: prolog

How can I find sequence from starting number to ending number in Prolog. My function should   look

```
findSequence(-4,-6,Z)---> Z=-4;Z=-5;Z=-6
```

Comment: I written the following two lines, If i trace it is going as I expected but it is printing the final value:<br>

Comment: Where are the following two lines?

Comment: @DanieLyons and Alejandro: I wrote the following findSequence(X,X,X). findSequence(X,Y,Z):-Y>X,X1 is X+1, findSequence(X1,Y,Z). The problem here is it is printing the final value. I want to print it for every value of X in the recursion.

Comment: Add `write(X)` between `X1 is X + 1` and `findSequence(X1, Y, Z)`.

Comment: It prints like 12345... I want to print the output variable = X

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you should be calling it `findSequence(-6, -4, Z)` instead of `findSequence(-4, -6, Z)`.

Comment: I tried with positive integers too. it was not printing that way...If i want to print a number with the given output variable we need to call a method by passing that value for example If i call printValue(Z). on already declared methods printValue(1). printValue(2). printValue(3). then it prints Z=1; Z=2; Z=3; I saw this way to print from example given in swi prolog demos. But its not a solutions here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a simple minded procedure

```
findSequence(N, N, N) :- !.
findSequence(S, E, N) :-
    S < E, (N = S ; T is S + 1, findSequence(T, E, N)).
findSequence(S, E, N) :-
    S > E, (N = S ; T is S - 1, findSequence(T, E, N)).
```

For any practical use you should check if [between](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)/3 could work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a recursive predicate in which you accumulate(in a list) values from the start value(-4) to the end value (-6).

Answer (score 0):

This should work. This takes into account that From<=To. A little more complex can be written if you want to check if

```
findSequence(X,X,[X]):-!.
findSequence(From,To,[From|Rest]):-SuccFrom is From +1, findSequence(SuccFrom ,To, Rest).
```

This returns a list,i.e.:

```
?-findSequence(1,3,List).
List=[1,2,3].
yes
```

Comment: `?- findSequence(-4,-6,S).` loops.

Comment: the problem here is that -4>-6... if you want to do it in reverse, change From+1 to From-1. So the correct way to call this will be: findSequence(-6,-4,S).

Comment: The problem is your incorrect use of the cut. Try `findSequence(1,3,[_,_,_,_|_])` which should fail. For `-4`, `-6` either failure (if you restrict yourself) or success is expected. But not looping.

Comment: With findSequence(1,3,[_,_,_,_|_]) you are trying to find a sequence with at least 4 member that of course will fail because the list from 1 to 3 has only 3 members. So check the list pattern you use as 3rd parameter. Try findSequence(1,3,[_,_|_]).The cut is to prevent other result that will be wrong.

Comment: Try findSequence(1,3,[ _ , _ | _ ]).

Comment: `findSequence(1,3,[_,_,_,_|_])` loops in your definition. But it should fail. You say "... that of course will fail..." but your definition does not fail, it loops.

Comment: The question concerns -4 and -6, so this isn't an answer unless that's addressed.

Comment: now i know what you mean with my solution loops.... you are more than right. But if add another clause, this issue will be solve

Comment: findSequence(X,Y,_):-X>Y,!,fail.
findSequence(X,X,[X]):-!.
findSequence(From,To,[From|Rest]):-SuccFrom is From +1, findSequence(SuccFrom ,To, Rest).

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny case where what you're asking isn't especially hard but you managed to ask it in such a roundabout way that we spent a lot of time trying to figure out what it was you wanted. You don't want a sequence (i.e. a list) at all, you want successive answers. And you want it to work with all the integers, not just natural numbers--this is implicit in your example, but not stated. Also, your example doesn't work with the naive solution, because -4 is greater than -6, which is the opposite of how this predicate would normally be written.

To deal with all of this, the simplest thing I'm confident in requires the library `clpfd`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We'll need a few helper predicates:

```
min(X, Y, Z) :- X < Y -> Z = X ; Z = Y.
max(X, Y, Z) :- X < Y -> Z = Y ; Z = X.
```

These just find the minimum and maximum; I would normally write them with two lines each but this is more expedient. Now the solution:

```
findSequence(X, Y, Z) :- 
  min(X, Y, Low),
  max(X, Y, High),
  Z in Low..High,
  label([Z]).
```

This takes care of your use case and the obvious ones.